# xib file shows in wrong target

Tags: cocoa, xcode, xib, targets

I am new to using multiple targets in a xcode project and have hit a snag that I can't find an answer for.

I have a project with two targets. One target does not have a user interface and the second target contains a user interface for administration. The problem that I am having is when I build and run the first target without the user interface, the user interface xib for the second target is still compiled and shown.

I have made sure that the xib file is only associated with the second target. What am I doing wrong? I would like to be able to run the first target without the user interface showing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have read the documentation at apple but found nothing that helped answer this specific question.

Comment: Please show us the fully-expanded target in your project, and the build log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter thanks for the reply. I finally figured it out today. I had not set the "Product Name" for the second target to be something different then the original target. Doing that resolved the problem.

-John